# Android Studio SharedPreferences of boolean and if conditions

Tags: java, android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

Task:
- When a save button is clicked: Save a checkbox's boolean value to SharedPreferences.
- On App boot check if the SharedPreferences value is true, if so check the checkbox.

Not sure in which part of the above i'm wrong, so i present you the whole thing. (Searched a lot the web and trying to solve this for days, excuse y newbie-city)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean ever_saved_settings=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String if_settings= String.valueOf(ever_saved_settings);
    if(if_settings.equals("true")) {
        SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String PU2 = Saved_Settings.getString("PU", null);
        if (PU2=="true")
            chk_box_PU.setChecked(true);
            else
            chk_box_PU.setChecked(false);

    }

public void save_settings(View v) {
    ever_saved_settings=true;
    CheckBox chk_box_PU = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_box_PU);
    String PU_value = (String) chk_box_PU.getText();
    SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = this.getSharedPreferences("Saved_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = Saved_Settings.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("PU", PU_value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Here arethe /xml's just in case the problem is not in the activity. Rare but possible for a newbie :}

toolbar_save_button.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:text="@string/save_button"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:onClick="save_settings"/>
```

which is included in:
home.xml

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
[...]
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_save_button"/>
</merge>
```

whish is included in:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/back_0"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
[...]
<include layout="@layout/home"/>
[...]
</LinearLayout>
```

The button looks just fine running the .apk in an android cell phone, it "blibs" when you click it.

Comment: Your ever saved settings will always be false at application start.

Comment: your problem  (PU2=="true")

Comment: Why do you need to convert booleans into Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You don't need this variable:

```
boolean ever_saved_settings=false;
```

This variable is set to false every time you launch your application.
Also you will not get any error if settings don't exist, so the variable is useless.

**2.** Your line

```
if (PU2=="true")
```

will always return false. In this line you are comparing pointers, not values.

Always use it in this way:

```
if (PU2.equals("true"))
```

**3.** Why do you store boolean values in a String, and compare them as Strings?

You can compare boolean variables, for example:

```
boolean variable = true;
if (variable) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

**4.** here is how you should implement it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getSharedPreferences("Saved_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    chk_box_PU.setChecked(Saved_Settings.getBoolean("PU", false));
}

public void save_settings(View v) {
    CheckBox chk_box_PU = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_box_PU);

    SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getSharedPreferences("Saved_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = Saved_Settings.edit();

    prefsEditor.putBoolean("PU", chk_box_PU.isChecked());

    prefsEditor.apply();
}}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for commenting on things,it helps learn also :}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getPreferences("Saved_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean PU2 = Saved_Settings.getBoolean("PU", false);

    // no need to check with if conditions. just set the button with the value(PU2)
    chk_box_PU.setChecked(PU2);

}

public void save_settings(View v) {
    CheckBox chk_box_PU = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_box_PU);
    SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = this.getSharedPreferences("Saved_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = Saved_Settings.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean("PU", chk_box_PU.isChecked());
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Replace the SharedPreferences get boolean default value with false and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the preference name:

```
   SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Change to:

```
   SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getPreferences("Saved_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate()
change this

```
SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences Saved_Settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

and this `if (PU2=="true")` to `if(PU2.equals("true"))`

Comment: Didn't work. thnx anyway. I'll try the other answers and i'll edit the post to add the .xml's just in case ...